# Typeparameter set from type argument

Tags: c#, type-parameter

How do I convert my argument to a proper type declaration. Ie. how do I go from `type` to `T` in the following

```
class Foo<T>
{  
  Foo<??> MakeFoo(Type type)
  {
    return new Foo<??>();
  }

  Void Get(T aFoo)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot.

Generic parameters are used and applied by compiler while `Type` is a part of Reflections that are designed to work with type information in run-time. So you just cannot define which type compiler should use if you have only `System.Type`.

However you can do the opposite:

```
public void Foo<T>()
{
  Type t = typeof(T);
}
```

So if you really do not need to use `Type` as a parameter you can do the following:

```
Foo<FooParam> MakeFoo<FooParam>()
{
  return new Foo<FooParam>();
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand. The reason I am somewhat reluctant to using your suggestion is, that there is a constructor on the class for non-reflection-use along with the factory-method shown above. The factory menthod is intended a use pattern with relection and thus constraints can sanely be set using the type-parameter. Envision a different Get() as above not taking a T as an argument but a set of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do such thing, because "Type" is a set of reflected metadata
of classes, structures and/or enumerations.

"T" is the type.

You can give the type as argument using reflection:

```
type.MakeGenericType(type).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null)
```

But I'll vote to add a generic parameter "S" instead of input parameter "Type type" in order to 
avoid the use of reflection, which is useless in this case if you do it right!